# readAttribute by classname in Prototype javascript

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am having a HTML like

```
<a href="yourpath/controller/views/username" class="classname">username</a>
```

How to read the attribute `href`'s value by classname using the Prototype.js.

Please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$$('.classname')[0].readAttribute('href');`

*Note that `$$` will always return an array.*

Answer (score 0):

```
$$('.className')[0].readAttribute('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

$$('.classname').pluck('href');

This will return an array of `href` values in case you need more than one.